# How to execute commands in LXTerminal on every Raspberry Pi Boot up

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot-issues

I am stalled at a point where I need to have multiple commands to be executed in parallel on LXTerminal to use a raspberry pi as an [Amazon Echo Device](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app).

Everything works fine If I launch the commands manually in separate terminals. I would like to execute the same commands automatically on pi boot directly on LXTerminal.

I tried using crontab option by adding in the bottom of the file

```
@reboot lxterm -e 'cd /home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/javaclient && mvn exec:exec;read x';
```

Unfortunately, it's not working and no Terminal is coming up on the boot of raspberry pi.

Please advice how to execute a command on an LXterminal on boot.

Comment: Do not simply post a link to some documentation and expect others to read it to find out what you *supposedly* did, are doing, etc.  **Explain it yourself.**  Again, this is not a restaurant and you are not a billionaire.  You are not entitled to help if you cannot make an effort to explain yourself clearly.

Comment: I modified my question based on ur request earlier . Anyone who has basic knowledge and worked on posted topic that  will obivously understand what I am asking for.  I do not want to confuse people by writing stories. Thats why we tag relevant topic. Yes I am not a billionaire nor u have to do charity by helping. This attitude was not expected by an admin. if not this forum there are other places else u can solve it on my own.  Was posting here so that others can make use also. I don't give a dime if u dont want to post. Sorry if it felt rude, but same applies to you.

Comment: Heads up that your link at the top is a 404 (I did not change that).  WRT to a solution, you are wise to look at the general case ("execute commands in LXterminal at boot"); the more general case, which you will find examples of if you dig around here, is how to execute a GUI application at boot (it is more complicated than straight commands -- **which you might want to check that those commands actually require this**, I'd bet they do not).

Comment: You seem to be confusing booting and starting GUI.

Comment: I'm not an Alexa user, but I am a java and shell user and the end of the command you have there looks odd.  What is `mvn exec:exec; read x` supposed to do?  Beware of falling into the [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) trap.  If you are trying to doing something but it doesn't work *and you don't understand how what you are doing works, or how what you want to do should work*, you should research (and ask about) that or you are likely to just dig yourself a deeper hole.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make a C program and by using the command "system", which lets you type terminal commands inside your program, and then that program of yours you can make it boot on startup! 
Here is a link with more information on the "system" command:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm

Comment: This doesn't explain how to run the command when the computer boots. This just explains how to run the command, even though sunil already knows how to run the command.

Comment: The link i posted is for the system command. A simple google search on how to make a program run when the pi boots is not that hard. First link on the search is about the rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rc.local file. Add `lxterm -e '..'` to the end of the file. Also, make sure to add an ampersand (`&`) so the Raspberry Pi doesn't stall at boot or login.